# Google map marker not showing because of border-box

Tags: css, google-maps

I've copied this code to add a basic google map to my site, and it's working fine
https://jsfiddle.net/qed5a8hc/
I added my own API key. However, the marker is not showing. It appears that this snippet in my css file is preventing it from showing, because when I comment it out, the marker shows up

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

I've tried solving this by adding the css

```
#map {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

and it's not working.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  max-width: 100%; 
}

#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: The fiddle you posted has absolutely nothing in it.

Comment: Oh darn, sorry... here's the code I used - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map - fiddle link is there

Comment: When I add your `*` rule to Google's fiddle, it still works fine. Please fork their fiddle and make a version that includes your CSS rule and actually fails.

Comment: Hmm it appears that the problem is actually a "max-width: 100%" rule, not the border-sizing... adding "max-width: none" does not solve things... here's a fiddle link that I hope illustrates the problem https://jsfiddle.net/qed5a8hc/

Comment: Why do you need `* {  max-width: 100%; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the code snippet. I noticed that the `*` rule in the snippet is different from the one in the original question. The question listed this one:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

The snippet has this:

```
* {
  max-width: 100%; 
}
```

But whatever. The rule in the snippet does break the map marker as you described.

The bottom line on this is simple:

**DO NOT use any `*` CSS rule on a page containing a Google Maps API map.**

This also applies to any similar kind of embedded widget, unless the widget is inside an `iframe`. Find another way to do whatever styling you are attempting with the `*` rule. It is difficult for the Maps API or other widgets to defend themselves against CSS styles like this.

`*` rules can also cause performance problems. At least this used to be the case; I haven't checked it lately.

There are several ways you could apply your `max-width` to only your own elements and not the `#map` element, but without knowing more about the structure of your document it would be hard to make a specific suggestion.

If you put the map inside an `iframe`, then everything changes. The map is in its own separate web page and not subject to the CSS on the main page. If you must use a `*` rule, then an `iframe` could be a good workaround for you.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'm working with a grid system and the * CSS rule stopped images and things from overflowing the grid, but I guess I'll find a workaround for this page.